# Playwright: "route.continue" occasionally gives error when blocking tracking scripts

Tags: javascript, browser-automation, playwright

I've got a synthetic monitoring test that has been running fine. I've added some code to block third-party ad tracking and analytic scripts to speed up the tests (and not skew analytics), as recommended here: https://scrapingant.com/blog/block-requests-playwright.

At the top of each test I've got this:

```
await page.route('**/*', filterResources)
```

And the `filterResources` method is defined as follows:

```
const DOMAIN_EXCLUSIONS = [
    'connect.facebook.net',
    'px.ads.linkedin.com',
    [...]
]

module.exports = (route) => {
    let matches = DOMAIN_EXCLUSIONS.filter((domain) => {
        return route.request().url().startsWith('https://' + domain)
    })
    return matches.length ? route.abort() : route.continue()
}
```

Now occasionally the following error will be thrown, and the test fails:

```
route.continue: Target page, context or browser has been closed
```

This maybe happens in one every 6-8 runs.

Is this because the page navigates away while some requests are still outstanding, because Playwright believes the page is already fully loaded? I'm using the proper awaits and the test was working fine before.

Comment: I'm now trying to always resolve the promise by returning `route.continue().catch(() => {})` instead. Let's see what happens.

Comment: This is non-answer, but you should avoid blocking the requests in the first place, and instead return data that reflect what is typically used by those endpoints. In case of Google Analytics, that would mean responding with 204 response. Here is a code example of that: https://ray.run/blog/blocking-google-analytics-in-playwright-tests

Comment: Thanks @LucGagan, that's actually a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm catching and solving the promise now, and the issue doesn't seem to happen any more:

```
if (matches.length) {
    return route.abort()
}

return route.continue().catch(() => {})
```